# Independence-like property of convex combinations in a vector space

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, convex-geometry, convexity

Consider the following property of a set of vectors $S\subset V$, where $V$ is a real vector space:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m w_ix_i
= \sum_{i=1}^m u_iy_i,\quad
x_i,y_i\in S,\quad
0\le w_i,u_i\le 1, \quad
\sum_iw_i=\sum_iu_i=1 \\
\implies w_i = u_{\pi(i)}
\,\text{for some permutation $\pi$}.
$$
It is implicit here that the $x_i$ are distinct, as are the $y_i$.
In other words, if two convex combinations of distinct vectors in $S$ are the same, then the *sets* of weights must be the same. This is a curious condition that recently came up in a problem, and I can't say I've seen it before. It is not hard to construct explicit examples (simply by solving the implied equations).

Does this property have a name, and/or are there characterizations of it? Is it equivalent to some perhaps more well-known property?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, edited. They should be distinct.

Comment: Is $m$ considered fixed or arbitrary?

Comment: Just to follow up on my previous comment: if $m$ is small compared to the dimension of $V$, then most finite sets will satisfy your condition. (Think about the case where $m = 2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. For a generic finite set of points, no four points are coplanar.)

Comment: Good question - I was thinking "for all finite $m$" (or at least, for all large $m$), but pointers on fixed $m$ are welcome. As you point out, the case $m=2$ can be worked out explicitly.

Comment: Do you have an example of such a set? There should be a bound on the cardinality of $S$ by the dimension of the vector space.